# static fields declared in the interface org.eclipse.gef.EditPolicy in eclipse GEF

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

Could someone explain the static fields declared in the interface org.eclipse.gef.EditPolicy(e.g COMPONENT_ROLE,CONNECTION_ROLE,CONNECTION_ENDPOINTS_ROLE etc).I have gone through the javadocs of the interface but the explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK they have no real meaning. When you install an edit policy you must give it a unique name, but I have never code that uses these name. You can freely ignore them :-)